# how to display large number of markers on google map using andorid?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display at least 4000 markers on android map but when I run the program the screen become unresponsive and the application get crashes ?? 
the posible solution may be thread or service but I don't know how to use these for android markers . Please help

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378354/android-out-memory-exception-in-map/35411350#35411350 Using threads is not an option because Markers can be added to the map only on the main thread

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/  it can help u for large numbers.

Comment: thanx  I'll check it@– Çağrı

Answer (score 2):

You can use google map clustering utility, by clustering your markers, you can put a large number of markers on a map without making the map hard to read.

Please go through the official documentation of [Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering)

You can also configure the sample code in your system [Marker Clustering - Sample Code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples)

Also make sure that your system have a updated versions of google play services and google play application in your device is updated.

Comment: Clustering is an excellent workaround but it clearly does not allow you to "put large numbers of markers on the map".