# Dynamic markers Google Maps - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have a memory problem with Google Maps when there are too many markers on the map : `OutOfMemoryError`. From what I've read on the Internet, it's bitmaps that are a problem. Bitmaps (all different from each other) are dynamically generated.

Here is my code of each dynamic bitmap :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View inflatedFrame = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_layout_map, null);
final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) inflatedFrame.findViewById(R.id.friend);

/** customizing the view **/

frameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
frameLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
frameLayout.layout(0, 0, frameLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), frameLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
frameLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), frameLayout.getMeasuredHeight(),
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
Drawable drawable = frameLayout.getBackground();
if (drawable != null)
    drawable.draw(canvas);
frameLayout.draw(canvas);
```

Then, each bitmap is used  :

```
@Override protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(Map_frag.Map_Cluster item, MarkerOptions markerOptions)
{
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(item.bm));
        /** item.bm is bm in the previous code extract **/
}
```

All this works well when there are 20 markers. But as soon as there are 50, for example, the `OutOfMemoryError` occurs.

So I tried several solutions:

- Enable `largeHeap` to the Manifest. This seems to allow adding a few more markers before the application crashes. But very quickly, the error occurs again.
- Release the memory used by each bitmap with the following code : `markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(item.bm)); 
  bm.recycle();
  bm = null;`
  But it doesn't work. The line `markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(item.bm));` crash saying that the bitmap can't be a recycle bitmap. Strange, because `bm.recycle()` is placed after the execution of this line.

So I don't know what to do anymore! Thank you in advance for your help. If some important pieces of code are missing I can add them.

Comment: Take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378354/android-out-memory-exception-in-map/35411350#35411350

Comment: If it's the only way ! Thanks